# Delete link button work after page refresh in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Here is my code for grid row delete using link button but after click its deleted data after page refresh I want delete data on the page without refresh the page i also put update panel in my grid here is my code

```
protected void gvContent_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="modify")
    {
        GridViewRow row = 
            (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

        // this find the index of row:
        int RowIndex = row.RowIndex; 

        //this store the  value in varName1:
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(
                   ((Label)row.FindControl("lblContentId")).Text.ToString()); 

        Response.Redirect("ContentManage.aspx?ContentId=" +Convert.ToInt32(id));
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)
                           (((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

        // this finds the index of row:
        int RowIndex = row.RowIndex; 

        //this stores the  value in varName1:
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(
                   ((Label)row.FindControl("lblContentId")).Text.ToString()); 

        Content_Data.DeleteContentDetails(id);
        BindGrid();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register gvContentas an async post-back control using the followin

```
 void Page_Load()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(gvContent);
        }

    }
```

This will cause your Grid to do async post-backs.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty RowDeleting event

```
 protected void gvContent_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```